# AngularJs: Change Style on Clicking div

Tags: angularjs, onclick

I am very new angularjs. I use the following code to select a div.

```
  var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#test' ) );
```

How can i add click event to "myEl" in controller rather than using "ng-click"?

My actual problem is to add click event on a div. Like the following,

```
 template += '<div class="ngdialog-maximize" ng-click="myStyle={'width':'100%','height':'100%'}"></div>';
```

The above div is maximize button in the modal pop up. On page referesh i could see errors in console. If i remove "ng-click" error is gone and modal pop up is working.

Errors:

```
  1. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  2. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing DOM manipulation in a controller? Generally, best practice is to do no DOM manipulation in a controller, that allows you to separate your model and logic from your view (the DOM) and test the controller without needing a DOM.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not working"? That's manager/user language, not programmer language. :-) Are you seeing an error? Is the page rendering but clicking seems to do nothing? etc

Comment: Sory, please check my updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the errors you are seeing with the original code is that you are using single quotes (`'`) to delimit the entire string you are appending to `template`, but also using single-quotes inside that string without escaping them using `\'`.

So just change your original line to:

```
template += '<div class="ngdialog-maximize" ng-click="myStyle={\'width\':\'100%\',\'height\':\'100%\'}"></div>';
```

Comment: No problems. As a tip, whenever you are asking for help, both on StackOverflow and in person to other programmers, try to remember to tell them _why_ you are trying to do something first, rather than just the specific solution you have come up with. They may be able to help you work out a better solution that avoids your current problem altogether.

Comment: Hi again, Can i ask u 1 more doubt? I have 2 divs, display one div at a time. Like, Initailly 1 div will be shown when i click on it toggle with another div and it continues. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Ensure both divs have the same `class`. Have the second div (the one to be initially hidden) have a `style="display: none;"` attribute. Then attach a click handler using [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`.on('click', ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to both divs that calls the [jQuery `.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method on both. If you get stuck, post a new question with where you got up to.